# Shopify Checkout Styling Bug

Tags: css, shopify, shopify-template

So I have this checkout page:
[image]

I'm trying to remove the yellow background color from the 'Show order summary' div.

However, on the theme editor, it shows up as expected:
[image]

The styling gets added due to a class which I can't figure out where it's coming from, as it isn't visible in the theme editor:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Shopify doesn't allow custom CSS to be inserted for the checkout page.

Comment: Its coming from Shopify. Have you checked the checkout style settings, if you're on the legacy checkout it would be in the theme settings if you're are using the new checkout it is in the store settings under. Have a look around and see if you see if you find that yellow

Comment: What Shopify plan, do you have? Shopify plus allows you the right code for checkout, if not then might be an app adding the same to checkout.

Comment: I use the free plan, theres a few apps installed but cant pinpoint which one is causing this!